# How to send associated data to server side in ext js4?

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4

I am new in extjs4 .I am using MVC structure.and I am going to save associated data to server side.I am getting stuck at this point. 
I have two tables 
1)

```
Question
========
qid
question

2)
Option
========
oid
option
qid
```

I am going to displayQuestion answer page. There are  10 questions diplays on the page at a time with their 4 options for each question.

I know how to save single instance of model in to database.

```
var check = Ext.ModelManager.create(
        {
            question:que,

        }, 'Bal.model.sn.QuestionModel');
check.save();
```

I am getting all the selected questions with there options.but I dont know how to save associated data to database.And how to create instance of particular models to instantiate model with data.. 
Here is my other model
'Bal.model.sn.optionModel'

How can i solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not provided out of box. Please take a look at this thread for some implementations of similar functionality: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store/page4